# How does MailChimp authenticate emails?

Tags: authentication, email

Keeping it short, [MailChimp states that](http://mailchimp.com/about/authentication/):

> **Authentication Should Be Simple**
>
> Email authentication is useless if it's too hard to implement. Many
>   email service providers require server setup in order to authenticate
>   your email campaigns. Accessing your server to modify DNS and TXT
>   records and modifying your MTA is just not practical (especially for
>   small businesses). At MailChimp, our authentication is free and
>   automatically added to your campaigns by default.

So that got me curious. How can MailChimp automatically authenticate emails without accessing my servers to modify my domain's DNS records?

(record types: SPF, DKIM, PTR, SenderID)

Comment: Have you tried [asking them](http://kb.mailchimp.com/accounts/management/mailchimp-support-options)?

Comment: @cremefraiche: No I haven't, but I did Google around, and since I didn't found an answer I thought it would be useful to ask the question here so it become accessible to other people with the same doubt in the future. But thanks for the link, I might ask there as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So that got me curious. How can MailChimp automatically authenticate
>   emails without accessing my servers to modify my domain's DNS records?

As far as I can see... they can't.

From [their own setup instructions](http://kb.mailchimp.com/delivery/deliverability-research/set-up-custom-dkim):

> To set up custom DKIM, you must create or edit two files, known as
>   "records," through your hosting provider, domain registrar, or DNS
>   provider.

And [from the very page you referenced](http://mailchimp.com/about/authentication/):

> Some methods (SPF, SenderID) simply require a file on your server that
>   can be cross-referenced by a receiver.

My guess is that either:

- They're talking about sending via one of their own domains rather than your own
- They mean it as an aspiration related to their participation in the  "Authentication and Online Trust Alliance" (which they link to underneath) rather than something which is true today

Comment: Your guess is right. I sent an email test message using MailChimp and I'm seeing a "via mail181.wdc02.mcdlv.net" next to the sender's name. So even though my domain's no-reply email address shows up as the sender, it's clear the the message is coming from MailChimp's email server.

Comment: @thexacre thank you for your guess, I was wondering how mailchimp is not spam while they don't do any authentication!